# how to get new student if y/n answer as a print statement on last line message

Tags: python, pycharm

```
sStudent = input("Are you a new student? y/n")
if "y" == sStudent:
    print**("Welcome to Henry Ford College!")**
elif "n" == sStudent:
    print**("Welcome back to HFC!")**

iCreditRate = input("Enter credit hour rate")
iNumCred = int(input("Enter number of credits this semester"))
sLabFee = input("Do you have any Lab fees?")`
```

## where welcome back or the welcome to message needs to be

Trying to get the new student y/n print messages to be shown only as the last line message at the very end of the program. `

Comment: Justajedi, welcome to StackOverflow, please try to improve the clarity of your question, right now we cannot understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```py
if "y" == sStudent:
    print("Welcome to Henry Ford College!")
elif "n" == sStudent:
    print("Welcome back to HFC!")
```

at the end of your program

Answer (score 1):

You could try to have a boolean variable to store the value and then at the end of the program you could have the if statement again and print the corresponding message based on the value of the boolean variable.